# Making objects hidden (not invisible) on print with Adobe LiveCycle Designer ES4

Tags: printing, adobe, hidden, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I created a dynamic form in Adobe LiveCycle. I have buttons inside my content to add zones dynamically.

The problem is I would like to hide these buttons when the form is printed. I can do this with the Visible (Screen Only) option, but objects still occupies space in the form layout. Is there a solution to completely remove objects on printing (make them invisible without occupying space).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the prePrint event to remove them from the layout. Also postPrint event to put them back in. Assuming that you are using flowed layouts, the objects won't occupy any space.

You just need to use

`this.presence = "hidden";`

to hide the button (on the prePrint event of the button).

`this.presence = "visible";`

to show the button (on the postPrint event)